# Let block gives indentation error

Tags: haskell

I know what an indentation error is, but I have no idea why I'm getting this error here, while every is aligned, trying to solve it for 2 hours.

```
Account.hs:40:25: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
40 |                         let amount = readLn :: IO Int
   |                         ^
Failed, 0 modules loaded.
```

```
main = do
            putStrLn $ "Press one to create a new account"
            let g = getLine
                enteredValue = read g :: Int
            if g == 1
                then do putStrLn $ "Enter your name "
                        let name = getLine
                            putStrLn $ "Enter the initial amount"
                            let amount = readLn :: IO Int
                                value  = Account (name,1,amount) Saving
                                show value
                else do putStrLn $ "Nothing"
```

I also tried this version but this also gives `incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets`:

```
main = do
        putStrLn $ "Press one to create a new account"
        let g = getLine
            enteredValue = read g :: Int
        if g == 1
            then do putStrLn $ "Enter your name "
                    let name = getLine
                        putStrLn $ "Enter the initial amount"
                        amount = readLn :: IO Int
                        value  = Account (name,1,amount) Saving
                        show value
            else do putStrLn $ "Nothing"
```

Comment: Btw. please don't use pictures to show 'text' based information - just copy paste the error message and add it like you did your source code. It is easier for search engines to index your content and it makes your question self-contained, if the hosting service of your picture is down the question cannot be answered/understood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
--                  |<---- "column 0" of this 'do' block 
            then do putStrLn $ "Enter your name "
--                  | still good; a 'let' statement:
                    let name = getLine
--                      |<---- "column 0" of this 'let' block
                        putStrLn $ "Enter the initial amount"
--                      | Huh, there's no '=' in ^this^ declaration?
                        let amount = readLn :: IO Int
--                      ^^^ Why is there a 'let' within another let binding?
--                          I still haven't seen a '='. Better throw a parse error.
```

Basically, `putStrLn $ "Enter the initial amount"` is aligned with `name = ...` in the preceding line, so the compiler reads it as a declaration (part of the same `let` block).

To fix your indentation errors, it should be:

```
main = do
            putStrLn $ "Press one to create a new account"
            let g = getLine
                enteredValue = read g :: Int
            if g == 1
                then do putStrLn $ "Enter your name "
                        let name = getLine
                        putStrLn $ "Enter the initial amount"
                        let amount = readLn :: IO Int
                            value  = Account (name,1,amount) Saving
                        show value
                else do putStrLn $ "Nothing"
```

But then you'll run into type errors:

- `read g` is wrong: `read` takes a `String`, but `g :: IO String`
- `g == 1` is wrong: `1` is an `Int`, but `g :: IO String`
- `show value` is wrong: `show` returns a `String`, but you're using it as an `IO` action
- You haven't shown the declaration of `Account`, but you're likely going to have issues with `name` and `amount`, too

You probably want something like:

```
main = do
            putStrLn $ "Press one to create a new account"
            g <- getLine
            let enteredValue = read g :: Int
            if enteredValue == 1
                then do putStrLn $ "Enter your name "
                        name <- getLine
                        putStrLn $ "Enter the initial amount"
                        amount <- readLn :: IO Int
                        let value  = Account (name,1,amount) Saving
                        putStrLn (show value)
                else do putStrLn $ "Nothing"
```

Basically, use `v <- expr` to go from `expr :: IO Something` to `v :: Something`.

Other notes:

- `g <- getLine; let enteredValue = read g :: Int` better written as `enteredValue <- readLn :: IO Int`
- `putStrLn (show value)` can be shortened to `print value`
- you don't need `do` for a single expression (nor `$` for a single operand): `... else putStrLn "Nothing"`

Answer (score 4):

There is more wrong to your code than just the `Indentation Errors` - so my first suggestion would be reading a bit of [learn you a haskell for great good](http://learnyouahaskell.com).

Next there are two assignment operators in haskell - one *bind*s the result of an action `… <- …` and the other one is a local definition/declaration of a pure computation `let … = …`.

Moreover you can improve your `read`ing a value by taking account of the possible false input, that someone could give you (intentionally and unintentionally) by replacing `read` with `readMaybe`, where the latter returns a `Maybe something`, for example  `readMaybe "1" = Just 1 :: Maybe Int` or `readMaybe "foo" = Nothing :: Maybe Int`.

Regarding your indentation it is best that you compare one solution to your program with yours own:

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

data Type = Saving | Checking
  deriving (Show)

data Account = Account (String,Int,Int) Type
  deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
        putStrLn "Press one to create a new account"
        g <- getLine
        let enteredValue = readMaybe g :: Maybe Int
```

> here the result of `getLine` and entered value have the same scope so they have the same indentation - we only change the scope after the next `if` where the `then`-block - and the `else`-block do not share the 'declarations' of each branch, so you couldn't use `name` in the `else`-block, but `enteredValue` can be used in both.

```
        if enteredValue == Just 1
            then do putStrLn "Enter your name "
                    name <- getLine
                    putStrLn "Enter the initial amount"
                    amount' <- fmap readMaybe getLine
```

> here again `name` and `amount'` share the same scope, and pattern matching on `amount'` creates a new scope where `amount` is visible and the match on `Nothing` where you cannot use this variable.

```
                    case amount' of
                      Just amount -> print $ Account (name,1,amount) Saving
                      Nothing -> putStrLn "Nothing"
            else putStrLn "Nothing"
```

Answer (score 4):

`let` is for binding values, which is done in the form `let x = y+z`, where `x` is the name (aka "identifier") being bound, and `y+z` is the expression to which it is being bound.

In your example, I see three bindings: `name`, `amount`, and `value`. The rest are not value bindings, but *actions*.

In the `do` notation, actions do not need a `let`. You just write them one after another. So:

```
let name = getLine
putStrLn $ "Enter the initial amount"
let amount = readLn :: IO Int
let value  = Account (name,1,amount) Saving
show value
```

But wait! This is not all!

`getLine` is not actually an expression of type `String`, as you seem to be hoping here. Rather, `getLine` is an *action*. In order to get it to "run" and "produce" a `String` value, you need to use the `<-` construct instead of `let`:

```
name <- getLine
```

Similarly with `readLn`:

```
amount <- readLn :: IO Int
```

Finally, `show value` is not actually an action that would print the value to the screen. `show` is a function that takes a value and return a `String`. It doesn't "do" anything (i.e. doesn't produce any outside effects), so you can't use it in place of an action in the `do` notation. If you wanted an *action* that would print a value to the screen, that would be `print`:

```
print value
```

Gathering everything together:

```
name <- getLine
putStrLn $ "Enter the initial amount"
amount <- readLn :: IO Int
let value = Account (name,1,amount) Saving
print value
```

And after fixing all of that, you'll have similar difficulties with the first part of your program, where you have `let g = getLine` instead of `g <- getLine`.